# Cant get Extended persmission.. :( Like email 

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi ive set a news facebook application like below but when i call the auth dialog the Email is not requested so i dont get any informations..

http://hpics.li/b91d453

Any idea ?

My FB request :

```
$data['get'] = array(
    'access_token'  => $access_token,
    'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'req_perms' => 'email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location,publish_actions',
    'ext_perms' => 'publish_stream',
    'fields' => 'email,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender,link,birthday,email,location'
);
```

And the PermissionDialog dont contain the email and the req_prems.. Why ?
And also Preview Current Dialog is different than Preview referal dialog (which contains emails etc)..
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which documentation are you working from? The parameter that needs to be passed to the Auth dialog to request additional permissions changed to 'scope' in October 2011

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for the permission info and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for how to authenticate

If you're doing server-side auth the URL to redirect the user to is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
    &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
    &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
```

And then you exchange the code for a token using the oauth endpoint (all this is covered in the docs above) - which your server makes a request to using the parameters below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK_AND_SENT_TO_YOUR_APP_IN_EARLIER_STEP
```